# Electron BrowserWindow hangs and becomes unresponsive

Tags: electron, window, freeze

We have builds of our application for mac and window with the Electron framework. And a lot of our users complain that the application sometimes hangs and becomes unresponsive. The Sentry monitoring shows that we have a lot of reports about that app become unresponsive and a lot of users with that problem. But when the app runs in the native browser, like Google Chrome, it doesn't happen.

Electron version 8.5.1 - this is the last 8.x version now. We can't move on the higher version, because there are some critical things that work correctly only on this one. This one for example - https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/24384 (It's closed but still not working).

Investigation of the Sentry logs didn't help us to understand what's the root of the cause. It happens at different times and we didn't find what it might depend on.

Just a senrty log example:
[image]

We made a workaround that helps to reload the application window.

```
window.on('unresponsive', () => {
   // there we can destroy window and create new
});
```

but it doesn't solve the root of the cause.

Could someone help to solve it or why can it be happening? Maybe someone has the same problems?

Comment: AFAIK, the `unresponsive` event fires after ~30 seconds. Your original image showed an error at that time. The new image also has events preceding the `unresponsive` event by that interval. Without seeing any application code I don't think there's much we can do. Look at the code that runs 30s prior to the `unresponsive` event.